# Packaging a font with a Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webfonts

I want to use something other than the standard fonts with my Chrome extension.  I was excited about the possibility of using the Google Web Fonts, but it seems that could incur a penalty for transferring the web font over the network whenever your extension uses it, to the point of affecting the performance of my extension.  Do I have any option for packaging a font with my extension that will work on all Chrome-supported platforms (Windows/Mac/etc.)?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 65):

Choose your font. As example I'll take ["Stint Ultra Expanded"](https://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse/Family:Stint+Ultra+Expanded). There is example how to add it to your page:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Stint+Ultra+Expanded' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Take only the `href` and open it in browser. You'll see something like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Stint Ultra Expanded';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Stint Ultra Expanded'), local('StintUltraExpanded-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/stintultraexpanded/v1/FeigX-wDDgHMCKuhekhedWmdhyVWfbygZe-w47Q2x_f3rGVtsTkPsbDajuO5ueQw.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Take first parameter of `url` value from `src` property (*http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/stintultraexpanded/v1/FeigX-wDDgHMCKuhekhedWmdhyVWfbygZe-w47Q2x_f3rGVtsTkPsbDajuO5ueQw.woff*).

Now download this file.

Use parameter of `local` value of `src` property as filename (*Stint Ultra Expanded*)

Easy way is to download it is using wget:

```
wget -O "Stint Ultra Expanded.woff" http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/stintultraexpanded/v1/FeigX-wDDgHMCKuhekhedWmdhyVWfbygZe-w47Q2x_f3rGVtsTkPsbDajuO5ueQw.woff
```

Now create css file and add content that you have seen before.
But you have to change value of `src` property. Remove all `local`s and adjust `url`. It should be smth like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Stint Ultra Expanded';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../fonts/Stint Ultra Expanded.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Now add your css file to extension and use the font:

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href='css/fonts.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>

    <span style="font-family: 'Stint Ultra Expanded';">Hello Font</span>

</body>
</html>
```

---

If you would like to use this font in content_script you have to adjust `url` in your css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Stint Ultra Expanded';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fonts/Stint Ultra Expanded.woff') format('woff');
}
```

You can add as many `@font-face` rules in your css as you like.

Notice: `local` value in `src` property tells you which name should be used to store it. It is good idea to use this name.

Second notice: If you are using it like google expected, your browser would check if this font is already available local. If this is not the case, then it would be downloaded and stored. So next time it would use font that was previously stored.

As of Chrome 37 (maybe earlier), you need to mention the font as a web accessible resource in the extension's manifest:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
  "font/*.woff2"
]
```

Otherwise you would see an error like:

```
Denying load of chrome-extension://{ID}/font/My Web Font.woff2. 
Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.
```

Comment: This does not work for packages apps.  'web_accessible_resources' is only allowed for extensions, hosted apps, and legacy packaged apps, but this is a packaged app.

Comment: I couldn't seem to get this method to work in the popup of my Chrome extension.

Comment: it's true that 'web_accessible_resources' is only allowed for extensions, but simply downloading and integrating the font (as described in the first part of the answer) works just fine in packaged apps.

Comment: Exactly which parts of `__MSG_@@extension_id__` need to be replace with my id?  For anyone else curious, the answer is "the whole part"

Comment: At the time as I wrote this answer (2013 - almost 6yr ago) there where no need to replace anything. This was exactly the URL you have to use. Today I don't know if there is any change. But as I see [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n#overview-predefined) it still seems still correct.

Answer (score 12):

This is quite old but for anyone still having issues with this, it is possible to load the font file with javascript. I had trouble getting a font-face declaration to work within shadow dom; all styles would load but chrome would just ignore the font-face declaration completely.

```
let font = new FontFace("yourFontName", "url('path/to/font/file.woff')");
document.fonts.add(font);
```

This works beautifully for me. Using font-face is probably preferred but I'm pretty sure my use case is a bug in chrome. [Here's the spec for it.](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-font-loading/#font-face-set-load)

Comment: That's the solution that worked for me, my use case seems similar to yours.

Comment: This results in 404 since the font file isn't on the file system of the site but of your extension.

Answer (score 8):

Asking the user for permissions to access Google Web Fonts is far less effort than embedding them (even if this might make perfect sense for eventual off-line scenarios).

**manifest.json**

```
"permissions": [
    "http://fonts.googleapis.com/",
    "https://fonts.googleapis.com/"
],
```

Comment: This will not work in packaged apps, but will work in extensions.

Comment: @WillScott did you find a solution for packaged apps?

Comment: How would you addt the CSS link then into the extension? I tried it in the manifest, but didn't work there.

Comment: You can use the `@import` css property in one of your css files.

Comment: this doesn't work, at least not in `manifest v3`