# Helvetica Neue on Ubuntu

Tags: html, web, google-chrome-extension, fonts

I wrote a very small chrome extension that shows you a picture and greets you good morning every time you open a tab.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/inspiral/pmoealnilgacefigomohkaciaoohgdlm

Unfortunately I noticed that the font I'm using "Helvetica Neue" doesn't work on my friends computer. He runs chrome on Ubuntu. How can I make the font load on his browser>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That font won't work for anyone who doesn't have it installed on their computer.

However, you can load a web font with your extension. Have you looked at this question: [Packaging a Font with A Google Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210451/packaging-a-font-with-a-google-chrome-extension)?