# Font not working in Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension for Google Chrome. I want to use custom fonts in my extension. I have declared a @font-face rule in my stylesheet like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Anonymous Pro";
    src: url("../assets/fonts/Anonymous-Pro/Anonymous-Pro-700.ttf");
}
```

But, this doesn't seem to work. I get an error like this:

```
GET chrome-extension://klcdnidgljemjhocdlalimcigcfmlbbk/assets/fonts/Anonymous-Pro/Anonymous-Pro-700.ttf net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Do I need to set any permissions in my manifest file to use custom fonts?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the font doesn't exist in the set location. Recheck your URL

Here is a much detailed answer on [Packaging a font with a Google Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19210451/2534513).

Comment: Hey. You're right. The URL was incorrect. But, I don't understand. I have named the folder as 'Anonymous-Pro', but the URL shows it as 'Anonymous-Pro.001'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: follow the link I have added.

Comment: I've already read that link. But, can you explain me why the folder got named 'Anonymous-Pro.001'. In fact, even the Finder on my Mac shows the name as 'Anonymous-Pro'.

Comment: I am not very sure how that happened.

Comment: also you must include other formats like eot, woff, svg to make the font work across all platforms.

Comment: This is an extension for Google Chrome. And Chrome supports TrueType format. So, I'm better off with just 'ttf' :)